# Git - setting up a remote repository on ec2 and doing an initial push

Tags: django, linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I'm following [this](http://thelucid.com/2008/12/02/git-setting-up-a-remote-repository-and-doing-an-initial-push/) tutorial to set up a remote repository on Amazon EC2.

When it comes to doing:  git push -u origin master
I get these errors:

1. src refspec master does not match any.
2. failed to push some refs to 'bitnami@xxxxxxxx.com:project.git'

I am using a bitnami djangostack image and I believe the problem originates from here. I have followed the exact same instructions and gotten it working when using a standard Amazon Linux image..

Comment: Those aren't the complete error messages.  Please post the full error, including the command that caused it (you can edit out the host name obviously).  Did you git init a directory on the host?  Do you have ssh access working?

Comment: Also check that the bitnami user has permission to the git repository or try to connect with a different user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means you did not configured the remote repository location correctly.

Need more information to solve this.